# Creating a Pie Chart on a single row but Multiple Columns in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pie-chart

Issue

I have cumulative totals in row 751 in my dataframe

I want to create a pie chart with numbers and % on just line 751

This is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
data = pd.read_csv('cleaned_df.csv')
```

In my .csv I have the following Columns

```
A,B,C,D,E,F

Rows under Columns(Letters) Rows( Numbers )
A= 123456
B= 234567
C= 345678
D= 456789
E= 56789
F= 123454
```

Lets say I want to create a pie chat with only Column B & D and F and the last row of numbers which would be row 6 (678994)

How do I go about that ?

Comment: Can you see the screenshot?

Comment: Test data and minimal reproducible code are supposed to be in text form, not as image.

Comment: I updated the info , Sorry I new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# set test data and create dataframe
data = {"Date": ["01/01/2022", "01/02/2022", "01/03/2022", "01/04/2022", ], "Male": [1, 2, 3, 6], "Female": [2, 2, 3, 7], "Unknown": [3, 2, 4, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Returns (where 3 is the target row for chart)

[image]

```
# set target row index, use 751 in your case
target_row_index = 3

# make the pie circular by setting the aspect ratio to 1
plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(1))

# specify data for chart
values = df.iloc[target_row_index, 1:]
labels = df.columns[1:]

# define function to format values on chart
def make_autopct(values):
    def my_autopct(pct):
        total = sum(values)
        val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
        return '{p:.2f}%  ({v:d})'.format(p=pct,v=val)
    return my_autopct

plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=make_autopct(values))
plt.show()
```

Shows

[image]